# Using the IP of 1 EC2 instance in a configuration file of Other EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, output, user-data

I am new to Cloud Formation.
I need a little help. I have created 2 EC2 instances using .yaml file. One is my database instance and other is my web instance. Now I have to give the IP of my database instance in a configuration file of my web instance.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the private IP address of an EC2 instance using `!GetAtt db-instance.PrivateIp` (where `db-instance` is the node name of that instance in your YAML template (at the top-level of the definition).

See: [AWS::EC2::Instance - Return Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance-return-values)

Comment: But how can I refer this output inside a config file?

Comment: You could create a User Data script as part of the CloudFormation definition, and refer to the IP address as part of that (it's a bit fiddly). Or, a more 'cloud-like' solution would be to apply a particular tag on the database instance (in the CloudFormation template), then your application could call `ListInstances()` and look for the instance that has that tag.